# angular 1.5 components communication/data sharing between controllers

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-controller, angular-components

I'm very new to the Angular-Typescript concept.

Set up is ***Typescript, Angular 1.5 components, if possible not to use $scope***

One component has search input fields. Another component should get the return value from service and render it.

As many articles online suggest to use service for data sharing between controllers(components). But these solutions don't really match my case. Its either pure angular or $scope or no using typescript.

***My results so far:***
If try to pass the variable through service is appears under the controller of the the first component. Controller of second component doesn't get hit neither the variable/parameter being passed(through constructor) has any value.

see the comments below for code example

Comment: if you could create the scenario in plunker, it would be of great help... cant understand anything without sample code

Comment: code sample/scenario (typescript doesn't seems to work in plunker though) 

      http://plnkr.co/edit/yxf8wffJLx67tu83q0K9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a variable from your controller to the components.

For example:
Define on each component a binding named `searchModel` that is 2-way binding
, so given `<comp-a>` and `<comp-b>` as the components, and controller `$ctrl` as the controller of the view where the components are used, you can do this:

```
<div>
    <!-- $ctrl is the controller of the view -->
    <comp-a search-model="$ctrl.search"></comp-a>
    <comp-b search-model="$ctrl.search"></comp-b>
</div>
```

Because the 2 components and bound to the same model on the view controller, if one changes it (for example, comp-a that is the "search" component), the other component will get the change also.

This is useful in case you can use multiple instances of the components, so you can connect each set of 2 components using a different model variable on the view controller.

```
<div>
    <!-- $ctrl is the controller of the view -->
    <comp-a search-model="$ctrl.search"></comp-a>
    <comp-b search-model="$ctrl.search"></comp-b>

    <!-- changes in $ctrl.search2 will not reflect to comp-b above, only the one below -->
    <comp-a search-model="$ctrl.search2"></comp-a>
    <comp-b search-model="$ctrl.search2"></comp-b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **angular** **events** to communicate between controllers in an async way. Subscribe your listener controller with **$scope.$on('inputChanges')** and when the input changes (you will have to use $watch or ng-change directive to detect the change) send the event with **$rootScope.$broadcast** or **$scope.$emit** (Which you should use is a matter of parent/children controller structure, see the difference at the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

About the $scope and not using it, Angular recommends now to use **ControllerAs** syntax, but there's no problem with using $scope at all. Just be careful on how to use **one time binding** to avoid unnecessary watchers and remember to inject it in your controller and constructor with **$inject**.